# Spring-amqp - Message processing delayed

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

We have a Java/spring/tomcat application deployed on a RHEL 7.0 VM, which uses AlejandroRivera/embedded-rabbitmq and it starts the Rabbitmq server as soon as the war gets deployed, and it connects to it. We have multiple queues that we use to handle and filter out events.

The flow is something like this:

event that we received -> publish event queue -> listener class filters events -->   publish to another queue for processing
                                                                                                                          ->  we publish to yet another queue for logging.

The issue is:

- Processing starts normally, we can see messages flowing though the queues, but after some time the listener class, stops receiving events. It seems like we were able to publish it to the RabbitMQ channel, but it never got out of the queue to the listener.
  This seems to start degrading causing events to be processed after some time, rising up till minutes. The load isn't as high, it's like around 200 events, from which we care about it's only a handful of them.

What we tried:

- Initially the queues had **pre-fetch set to 1**, and consumers to be **min of 2 and max of 5**, we removed pre-fetch and we added more consumers as max concurrency setting, but the issue is still there, the delay just takes longer to present, but after a few minutes, the processing starts to take around 20/30 seconds.

We see in the logs that we published the event to the queue, and we see the log that we got it off the queue with a delay. So there's nothing running in our code in the middle to generate this delay.

As far as we can tell, the rest of the queues seem to process messages properly, but it's this one that gets in this stuck mode..

The errors that I see, are the following, but I'm usure what it means and if it's related:

```
Jun  4 11:16:04  server: [pool-3-thread-10] ERROR com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler - Consumer org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$InternalConsumer@70dfa413 (amq.ctag-VaWc-hv-VwcUPh9mTQTj7A) method handleDelivery for channel AMQChannel(amqp://agent@127.0.0.1:5672/,198) threw an exception for channel AMQChannel(amqp://agent@127.0.0.1:5672/,198)
Jun  4 11:16:04  server: java.io.IOException: Unknown consumerTag
Jun  4 11:16:04  server: at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicCancel(ChannelN.java:1266)
Jun  4 11:16:04  server: at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor180.invoke(Unknown Source)
Jun  4 11:16:04  server: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Jun  4 11:16:04  server: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
Jun  4 11:16:04  server: at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:955)
Jun  4 11:16:04  server: at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.basicCancel(Unknown Source)
Jun  4 11:16:04  server: at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$InternalConsumer.handleDelivery(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:846)
Jun  4 11:16:04  server: at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149)
Jun  4 11:16:04  server: at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:100)
Jun  4 11:16:04  server: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
Jun  4 11:16:04  server: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
Jun  4 11:16:04  server: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This one happens on shutdown of the application, but I've seen it happen while the application is still running..

```
2018-06-05 13:22:45,443 ERROR CachingConnectionFactory$DefaultChannelCloseLogger - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 109, class-id=60, method-id=120)
```

I'm not sure how to address these two errors, nor if they are related.

Here's my Spring config:

```
<!-- Queues -->
<rabbit:queue id="monitorIncomingEventsQueue" name="MonitorIncomingEventsQueue"/>
<rabbit:queue id="interestingEventsQueue" name="InterestingEventsQueue"/>
<rabbit:queue id="textCallsEventsQueue" name="TextCallsEventsQueue"/>
<rabbit:queue id="callDisconnectedEventQueue" name="CallDisconnectedEventQueue"/>
<rabbit:queue id="incomingCallEventQueue" name="IncomingCallEventQueue"/>
<rabbit:queue id="eventLoggingQueue" name="EventLoggingQueue"/>

<!-- listeners -->
<bean id="monitorListener" class="com.example.rabbitmq.listeners.monitorListener"/>
<bean id="interestingEventsListener" class="com.example.rabbitmq.listeners.InterestingEventsListener"/>
<bean id="textCallsEventListener" class="com.example.rabbitmq.listeners.TextCallsEventListener"/>
<bean id="callDisconnectedEventListener" class="com.example.rabbitmq.listeners.CallDisconnectedEventListener"/>
<bean id="incomingCallEventListener" class="com.example.rabbitmq.listeners.IncomingCallEventListener"/>
<bean id="eventLoggingEventListener" class="com.example.rabbitmq.listeners.EventLoggingListener"/>

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" message-converter="defaultMessageConverter" concurrency="5" max-concurrency="40" acknowledge="none">
    <rabbit:listener queues="interestingEventsQueue" ref="interestingEventsListener" method="handleIncomingMessage"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" message-converter="defaultMessageConverter" concurrency="5" max-concurrency="20" acknowledge="none">
    <rabbit:listener queues="textCallsEventsQueue" ref="textCallsEventListener" method="handleIncomingMessage"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" message-converter="defaultMessageConverter" concurrency="5" max-concurrency="20" acknowledge="none">
    <rabbit:listener queues="callDisconnectedEventQueue" ref="callDisconnectedEventListener" method="handleIncomingMessage"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" message-converter="defaultMessageConverter" concurrency="5" max-concurrency="30" acknowledge="none">
    <rabbit:listener queues="incomingCallEventQueue" ref="incomingCallEventListener" method="handleIncomingMessage"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" message-converter="defaultMessageConverter" concurrency="1" max-concurrency="3" acknowledge="none">
    <rabbit:listener queues="monitorIncomingEventsQueue" ref="monitorListener" method="handleIncomingMessage"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" message-converter="defaultMessageConverter" concurrency="5" max-concurrency="10"  acknowledge="none">
    <rabbit:listener queues="EventLoggingQueue" ref="eventLoggingEventListener" method="handleLoggingEvent"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="${host.name}" port="${port.number}" username="${user.name}" password="${user.password}" connection-timeout="20000"/>
```

I've read here that the delay on processing could be caused by a network problem, but in this case the server and the app are on the same VM. It's a locked down environment, so most ports aren't open, but I doubt that's what's wrong.

More logs: https://pastebin.com/4QMFDT7A

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I need to see much more log than that - this is the smoking gun:

```
Storing...Storing delivery for Consumer@a2ce092: tags=[{}]
```

The (consumer) `tags` is empty, which means the consumer has already been canceled at that time (for some reason, which should appear earlier in the log).

If there's any chance you could reproduce with 1.7.9.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, I added some TRACE level logging which should help diagnosing this.

**EDIT**

In reply to your recent comment on rabbitmq-users...

Can you try with fixed concurrency? Variable concurrency in Spring AMQP's container is often not very useful because consumers will typically only be reduced if the entire container is idle for some time.

It might explain, however, why you are seeing consumers being canceled.

Perhaps there are/were some race conditions in that logic; using a fixed number of consumers (don't specify max...) will avoid that; if you can try it, it will at least eliminate that as a possibility.

That said, I am confused (I didn't notice this in your Stack Overflow configuration); with `acknowledge="none"` there should be no acks being sent to the broker (NONE is used to set the `autoAck`)

```
String consumerTag = this.channel.basicConsume(queue, this.acknowledgeMode.isAutoAck(), ...
```

and

```
public boolean isAutoAck() {

    return this == NONE;

}
```

Are you sending acks from your code? If so , the ack mode should be MANUAL. I can't see a scenario where the container will send an ack for a NONE ack mode.